# Is it possible to change the content text or message of a repeating notification in android ? If yes, how?

Tags: android, notifications, dynamic-programming, android-notifications

I have a repeating notification in a broadcast receiver. I will like to replace the content text dynamically. The notification will show the user a different message the next time the notification is shown. I want to know if its possible. If yes, how ?

below is the class of my broadcast receiver

```
public class TimeAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
NotificationManager nm;
long pattern[] = {500, 500};
private Uri notifsound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
private NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle contentStyle;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String msg = "Drivers who sit higher feel as if they're driving slower. " +
            "Thus, SUV drivers, who are already piloting the vehicles most prone to " +
            "roll, drive faster because they feel like they're creeping along. " +
            "So lower your seat to get the sensation of more speed.";


    contentStyle = new android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
    contentStyle.bigText(msg);
    contentStyle.setBigContentTitle("Lower Your Seat");
    contentStyle.setSummaryText("AutoKit");

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    builder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("AutoKit")
            .setContentText("Tip of the Day")
            .setTicker("Daily Tip")
            .setStyle(contentStyle)
            .setSound(notifsound)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setVibrate(pattern);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.notify(1, builder.build());
    } 

}
```

here is the method is called in my mainactivity and ties the broadcast receiver to an alarm manager

```
public void setRepeatingAlarm(){ //user receives notifications every 24 hours at 7am
    am = (AlarmManager)this.getSystemService(this.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, TimeAlarm.class);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 07);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, pi);
}
```

Comment: Notification or Notification messages are handled from WEB-SERVICES.. From application side you have to fetch that message and simply notify that.

Comment: "Notification or Notification messages are handled from WEB-SERVICES"?? what does this mean?

Comment: @NikPatel  "Notification or Notification messages are handled from WEB-SERVICES " What does it mean ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here the changes I made in the broadcast receiver class.

```
public class TimeAlarm extends BroadcastReceiver {
NotificationManager nm;
long pattern[] = {500, 500};
private Uri notifsound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
private NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle contentStyle;
private List contentTexts, contentTitles;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    contentTexts = new ArrayList<String>();
    contentTitles = new ArrayList<String>();
    prepareContentTitles();
    prepareContentTexts();

    SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("notification_count", context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int count = prefs.getInt("notification_count", 0);

    contentStyle = new android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
    contentStyle.bigText((CharSequence) contentTexts.get(count));
    contentStyle.setBigContentTitle((CharSequence) contentTitles.get(count));
    contentStyle.setSummaryText("AutoKit");

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    builder = (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("AutoKit")
            .setContentText("Tip of the Day")
            .setTicker("Daily Tip")
            .setStyle(contentStyle)
            .setSound(notifsound)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setVibrate(pattern);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(), PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    nm = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    nm.notify(1, builder.build());



    if (count == contentTexts.size() - 1) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("notification_count", 0);
        editor.commit();
    }
    else {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("notification_count", count + 1);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
public void prepareContentTexts() {
    contentTexts.add("Drivers who sit higher feel as if they're driving slower. " +
            "Thus, SUV drivers, who are already piloting the vehicles most prone to " +
            "roll, drive faster because they feel like they're creeping along. " +
            "So lower your seat to get the sensation of more speed.");
    contentTexts.add("Manufacturers recommend replacing your blades every three months. " +
            "Keep a spare set in your trunk. A product such as Rain Clear can also help " +
            "minimize the work of your wipers; spray it onto the glass every few weeks. " +
            "In some light rains, it makes the wipers almost unnecessary");
    contentTexts.add("At the BMW Performance Driving School, instructor Jim Clark says " +
            "these four words over and over: \"Slow in, fast out.\" When taking a corner," +
            " you need to scrub as much of that speed as you can while the car is braking" +
            " in a straight line, then you can accelerate out of the curve. The converse " +
            "is \"Fast in, maybe no out.\"");
}
public void prepareContentTitles() {
    contentTitles.add("Lower Your Seat");
    contentTitles.add("Rainproof Your Windshield");
    contentTitles.add("Maneuver Tight Corners ");
}

}
```

The notification displays different content texts every time it is fired

Answer (score 2):

Modify a Notification

To set up a notification so it can be updated, issue it with a notification ID by calling NotificationManager.notify(ID, notification). To update this notification once you've issued it, update or create a NotificationCompat.Builder object, build a Notification object from it, and issue the Notification with the same ID you used previously.

The following snippet demonstrates a notification that is updated to reflect the number of events that have occurred. It stacks the notification, showing a summary:

```
mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// Sets an ID for the notification, so it can be updated
int notifyID = 1;
mNotifyBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setContentTitle("New Message")
    .setContentText("You've received new messages.")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notify_status)
numMessages = 0;
// Start of a loop that processes data and then notifies the user
...
    mNotifyBuilder.setContentText(currentText)
        .setNumber(++numMessages);
    // Because the ID remains unchanged, the existing notification is
    // updated.
    mNotificationManager.notify(
            notifyID,
            mNotifyBuilder.build());
```

...

Taken from developer site. please refer, http://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/managing.html

Comment: I have edited the question. It will give you more info on what am trying to do.

Comment: from your code it seems you are always sending static data for setContentTitle and setContentText then how can you be able to see new text in the notification. Change your message for notification and check it will work.